# Can't disable SQL parenthesis auto-complete in Eclipse

Tags: mysql, sql, eclipse, autocomplete

I've been through the preferences in Eclipse, and I can't figure out how to disable code completion for files like `.sql`

Take this for example:

```
WHERE
  `key` = ''
  AND key_expires > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

When I edit the `WHERE` clause, I get this:

```
WHERE
  ()`key` = '' OR `key` IS NULL)
  AND key_expires > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I've tried turning off every option for parens, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the preferences go to Data Management -> SQL Development -> SQL Editor

Click on the 'Typing' tab, Uncheck 'Close parentheses' and click Apply/OK

I hope that works for you, it does for me.